# Fetch json_encode from php in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch

try to pass json_encode variable in php to javascript. get an uncaught error in javascript. It works before, not changing anything, and now it doesnt work?!?

JSON variable is fine from PHP. Try to print_r in php, OK. Browser networks also OK.

variables I want to pass in PHP:

```
$response['id'] = $id;
$response['name'] = $name;
$response['note'] = $note;
$response['image'] = $image;

$response['bumbu'] = $bumbu;
$response['banyak'] = $banyak;

$response['masak'] = $masak;

$response['images'] = $images;

print_r($response);
json_encode($response);
```

my javascript:

```
$('#viewResep')
  .on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget)
      .data('id');
    console.log('Requested : ' + id);

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.getAllResponseHeaders();
      }
    };

    xhttp.open('GET', 'process_post.php?view=' + id, true);
    xhttp.send();

    fetch('process_post.php?view=' + id)
      .then(text => JSON.parse(text))
      .then((data) => {

        r_Name = data.name;
        r_Note = data.note;
        r_Image = data.image;
        r_Bumbu = data.bumbu;
        r_Banyak = data.banyak;
        r_Masak = data.masak;
        r_Images = data.images;
      });
  });
```

I want to get all variables passed using json_encode in my javascript

Comment: You printed the `print_r` output, and discarded the `json_encode` result. Remove `print_r` and add `echo` to the next line.

Comment: remove the `print_r()` and just `echo json_encode($response);`

Comment: You do not need both `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch()` since they're both doing fundamentally the same thing. Just use `fetch(\`process_post.php?view=${encodeURIComponent(id)}\`).then(res => res.json()).then(data => { ... })`

Comment: localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Make sure your PHP script does not `echo`, `print` or otherwise output anything other than `echo json_encode($response);`. At the moment, it looks like it's printing some HTML. Please see the duplicates linked at the top of your question

Comment: Thanks Phil.. I'll take a look

Comment: U are right Phil !! I accidently put print_r somewhere on top. now its working, but dont pass the array correctly to javascript. bah!

Answer (score -2):

Use Ajax instead of this...........

**Updated**->

***PHP Page***

```
$response['id'] = $id;
$response['name'] = $name;
$json = array("id" =>$response['id'],"name" =>$response['name']);
```

***JS***

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "myphppage.php",
success: function(result) {
alert(result.id);
alert(result.name);
}
});
```

Comment: $ajax return a not a function error

Comment: ``$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "myphppage.php",
  success: function(result) {
   alert('success');
   }
  }       
});``

Comment: share your exact error here..

Comment: resep.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (resep.js:8)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at o.t.show (modal.js:119)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (modal.js:535)

Comment: check my update answer or check here also... Use Ajax instead of this...........


**Updated**

**PHP Page**
``$response['id'] = $id;
$response['name'] = $name;
$response['note'] = $note;
$response['image'] = $image;

$response['bumbu'] = $bumbu;
$response['banyak'] = $banyak;

$response['masak'] = $masak;

$response['images'] = $images;
$json = array("id" =>$response['id'],"name" =>$response['name']);``

**JS**

``$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "myphppage.php",
  success: function(result) {
   alert(result.id);
            alert(result.name);
  }       
});``

Comment: OP is using jQuery-slim, there is no `$.ajax` method

Comment: keeps returning the same $ajax is not a function error.. am I missing something here?

Comment: can't understand your words @Phil

Comment: did you add jquery.min.js @Abram

Comment: OP (Original Poster) aka @Abram is using jQuery-slim, not the full version of jQuery. jQuery-slim does not include any AJAX functions. There is no reason to include the full version of jQuery because `fetch()` (which they are using in their question) does the job just fine

Comment: First you can use this cdn instead of jquery-slim: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Abram please don't. You do not need jQuery's AJAX functions

Comment: did you try anything apart from this? @Abram

Comment: Check this newly updated answer buddy... @Abram